# Why is there an error in the following code? Why is the overloading not successful?

Tags: java, generics, overriding, overloading

```
// signatures of the reset method at //1 and //2 after erasure will be different
// then why don't they overload?

public class Test<T>{
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        WordBox<String> city = new WordBox<String>("Skogland"); 
        city.reset("waiting");  // error: ambiguous 
    }
}


class Box <T> { 
    private T theThing; 
    public Box( T t) { theThing = t; } 
    public void reset( T t) { theThing = t; } //1  
} 

class WordBox< S extends CharSequence > extends Box< String > {
    public WordBox( S t)    { super(t.toString().toLowerCase()); }
    public void reset( S t) { super.reset(t.toString().toLowerCase()); }  //2
}
```

Comment: Nice demonstration of how Java is not an improvement on C++ (which has no trouble with this scenario, either when base class methods are hidden or when they are brought into the search space by `using`).

Comment: @Ben Voigt -- ah, well, with subclassing a generified class, you'd typically expect the child class to specify the same type parameter at both levels, in whiche case user439526's example would work perfectly fine and appear perfectly intuitive to a lot of Java 5+ programmers. There are plenty of ways to make trouble for yourself in both Java and C++, but then, that's why we have sites like Stack Overflow, right? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`java.lang.String` extends `CharSequence`, so calling `city.reset("waiting")` matches both `WordBox.reset(S extends CharSequence)` and `Box.reset(String)`.

To fix the problem, you should either ensure `WordBox.reset()` accepts the same type as `Box.reset()`, in which case `WordBox.reset()` overrides `Box.reset()`, or, conversely, make sure `WordBox.reset()` accepts a type that does not overlap with `Word.reset()`, in which case `WordBox.reset()` overloads `Box.reset()`. In the example you give, I get the feeling you'd probably want `WordBox.reset()` to override `Box.reset()`.

Comment: So if they both match then why are they not override equivalent? And wont the subtype reset signature be reset(CharSequence) and supertype have reset(String).

Comment: Because they are in fact not the same type. In your example, Box.reset() will only accept instances (and subclasses) of String, whereas WordBox.reset will accept instances of CharSequence, which includes String, but also StringBuffer as well as any other custom extension of CharSequence

Comment: As I wrote in the first paragraph of my answer, city.reset("waiting") matches both WordBox.reset(S extends CharSequence) and Box.reset(String), hence the ambiguity error.  Unless you have other concerns that prevent doing this, I would recommend specifying WordBox as WordBox<S extends CharSequence> extends Box<S>.

Comment: So the signature after erasure will be reset(CharSequence) the other will be reset(String), in that case why should overloading not be successful

Comment: The overloading is successful, but the compiler doesn't like it when you call reset with a String instance, because String extends CharSequence, so String matches both reset(CharSequence) and reset(String)